# SUMIF with complex conditions using Matrix

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm used to use some matrix formulas in excel, but I'm not being capable of solving this one.

I'm working with a database about a firms expenditures on Human Resources that is structured with the following columns:

```
[Month] / [Type_Of_Expenditures] / [Employee_Name] / [Value]
```

In this structure, an employee may appear many different times (on many different lines) on a single month, because he recieves different types of payments, such as wages, benefits, etc.

One type of expense the firm can have with an employer is layoffs. Everytime an employee is fired, a line appears where `[@Type_Of_Expenditures]="Lay_Off"` and the cost of firing this employee appears on `[@Value]`

What I'm trying to do is the following: I want to sum the total cost for a month considering only those employees who hasn't been fired. But my problem is: if the employer `"Ana"` has been fired on that month, she will not only recieve a `"Lay_Off"` expense, but also other expenses such as `"Wage"`. So we can have, for instance:

```
[Month] // [Name] // [Type_of_expenditure] // [Value]
[...]
01/2016 // Ana // Lay_off // U$100 
01/2016 // Ana // Wage // U$400
[...]
```

My problem is creating a SUMIF structure that will sum all the `[Values]` conditioned on a specific `[Month]` but that will **not** sum if the employer has been fired on that specific month, regardless what is the `[Type_Of_Expedniture]`. In the `"Ana example"`, I don't want to sum neither the upper nor the lower line I described above.

To make things worse, we're talking about a table with over 80,000 lines, so efficiency matters.

Can anyone give me a help on this?

Answer (score 0):

Use an array formula like this:

```
=SUM(IF((MONTH(G1)=MONTH($A$2:$A$22))*(YEAR(G1)=YEAR($A$2:$A$22))*(B2:B22=G2)*ISERROR(MATCH($C$2:$C$22&"LAY_OFF",$C$2:$C$22&$B$2:$B$22,0)),$D$2:$D$22))
```

It will exclude any employee that was laid of in the specified month.

Being an array formula it must be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  If done correctly then excel will put {} around the formula.

[image]

Just for FYI, the total wages if George is include would have been 11550.

---

**EDIT**

This can also be done with the SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT((MONTH(G1)=MONTH($A$2:$A$22))*(YEAR(G1)=YEAR($A$2:$A$22))*(B2:B22=G2)*ISERROR(MATCH($C$2:$C$22&"LAY_OFF",$C$2:$C$22&$B$2:$B$22,0)),$D$2:$D$22)
```

But this may be a little more finicky than the formula above.